# Return nil on NSInteger return type method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, null

I have the following UITableView DataSource method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

On some items (i.e. section index titles) I just want to return "nothing", so that the table view won't jump to any section. I tried to return nil, but I get the "Return makes integer from pointer without a cast" - warning, since NSInteger is obviously not an object, just a typedef for 32/64 bit integers.

How can I achieve no return / reaction on specific section index titles?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Returning `nil` is an error here since you're returning an integer primitive, not an object. (You're getting a cast warning because `nil` is actually a `#define` that evaluates to `((void *)0)`, which is a null pointer, not an integer zero.) The best option for Objective-C code that interfaces with Cocoa is probably to use **`NSNotFound`**, a `#define` for `NSIntegerMax` which is used throughout Cocoa to signify that a given value does not exist in the receiver, etc. (Another option is to use `-1`, which is more common in C code. What works best depends on what the calling code expects and can handle.)

Although `NSNotFound` is a signed value, it's big enough that you're highly unlikely to run into a range issue. (`NSIntegerMax` is approximately half of `NSUIntegerMax`, and very few people get remotely close to 2,147,483,647 objects — let alone twice that many — in 32-bit land. In 64-bit, forget about it; you'll run out of physical RAM in your machine long before you run out of integers for indexes.)

Speaking of which, the Cocoa convention is to use `NSUInteger` (rather than `NSInteger`) for indexes. An unsigned integer cannot be negative, which offers *some* sanity protection on index values; among other things, it becomes easier to sort out accidental integer overflow/underflow. If this is a custom data source method (as it seems to be) I'd strongly suggest switching to using unsigned integers. (It may help to remember/realize that `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` occupy the same number of bytes, they just interpret the bits differently, so you won't "waste" any space by switching types.)

Comment: It's few years older app I've had to start doing maintenance. And while maintaining the code, I see currently 170+ warnings within XCode. Well few are causing by this error! :-)
Thanks! (Y)